# How to get a unique code in a module for installation?

Tags: module, magento-1

I have the need of the installed module has a single reference to query a webservice that returns the records of your reference.

I have this reference currently saved in a database table working properly, but I think unnecessary only 1 record in the table to contain the reference.

I was wondering if there are other ways to save this reference on Magento, per file, or some table of database of Magento, so I can delete this table with a single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your module `config.xml` file add following code inside `<config>` node:

```
<default>
    <your_module>
        <settings>
            <service_url><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/]]></service_url>
        </settings>
    </your_module>
</default>
```

To retrieve the value use:

```
$serviceUrl = Mage::getStoreConfig('your_module/settings/service_url');
```

You can save your value to database like this:

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('your_module/settings/service_url', 'Your data');
```

Your data will be saved in `core_config_data` table. If you call `Mage::getStoreConfig()` now data from database will be returned instead of the one defined in `config.xml` because database is loaded last it will 'overwrite' the value in config.xml`

Comment: Even if it would work, I would need to pass a method within the '<service_url> </ service_url>', so to exclude the module loses the reference, and the database does not lose = /

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you =D